# Where to store authentication token in RESTful API?

Tags: rest, spring-security, access-token

I want to secure the REST URL. For that I have decided to go with token based authentication. In that, how can I create the token with expiration time and where can I store it for later validation token check ?

Thanks in advance.

```
This is my security.xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
    <beans:import resource="applicationContext.xml"/>
    <http pattern="/jaxrs/employess/**" create-session="stateless"  entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern='/jaxrs/employess/**' /> 
            <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="myAuthenticationFilter" />
    </http>
    <beans:bean id="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="restservice.security.MyAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
    <beans:bean id="myAuthenticationFilter" class="restservice.security.MyAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>
    <!--<beans:bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"/>-->
    <beans:bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <!--  <beans:property name="errorHandler" ref="customErrorHandler" /> -->
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="restservice.security.MyAuthenticationProvider" >
        <beans:property name="restTemplate" ref="restTemplate"/>
    </beans:bean>
  <!--   <beans:bean id="customErrorHandler" class="com.AuthenticationResponseErrorHandler"/> -->
</beans:beans>*
```

Comment: You don't. Spring security handles this for you.

Comment: Can u post the example how it handles by spring ???

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store it anywhere, since that would imply storing some session state on the server.

Instead, the token itself should be a signed encoded string with the information you need to identify the user. You verify its authenticity by checking the signature. If you need to expire it, just append a time stamp to it before signing and calculate the token age based on the current time.

Comment: whether oauth is suitable for this requirement?

Comment: If we shouldn't persist the token (JSON web tokens for example) in the REST API database, how can we implement a "remember me" feature in a SPA -> REST api architecture? Only way I can think of is to use SPA -> App server -> REST api architecture so we can use sessions (persisted in the db of the app server) to be able to add a "remember me" feature in the single page app.

Comment: The API may provide a token that can be checked for authenticity, integrity and expiration without being stored on the server-side.